# What happens to Force users that are denied training by the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

I recently asked a question about [why the Jedi might not train Force users](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117158/4650), but as I was asking that, I realized that there was a second question...

What happens to those who are denied training? Presumably Anakin wasn't the only Force user where the question of whether or not to train them was raised.

As mentioned in the answers on my other question, there's a possibility that the Sith might draw these over to the Dark Side... so do the Jedi put them on ice? Do they simply monitor these individuals?

It seems like there would be too few Jedi to monitor *everyone* who's shown some kind of ability with the Force...

Comment: Not a full answer, but at the time that Anakin was denied training, the Sith were in hiding for the last thousand years and the Jedi had thought that the Sith were gone for good. If they were concerned about others corrupting rejected Force-hopefuls, it wasn't the Sith they were worried about.

Comment: I was pretty sure this is a duplicate, but somehow I cannot find the question. Anyone else who knows it?

Answer (score 2):

The Jedi do not refuse to take force sensitive children with them. They decide whether to train them as padawan or not later on during discussion with the Jedi council. If they decide not to train the individual it will become a part of the agricultural corps. The corps is an institution formed by the Jedi to help out on other planets.

This almost happened to obi-wan also, because nobody wanted to train him. It just did not happen because of qui-gon.taking obi-wan as apprentice.

I will give proof to this answer later on.

Comment: Did you find your proof? ;)

Comment: Not yet I got a whole bookshelf full of sw books and have to read a lot besides working and playing with my son. I am really on it.

Comment: Update: The Book I am speaking of is one of the clone wars books written by Sean Stewart. The title is dark rendezvous. I will search for the passage now.

Comment: They were actually sent to the jedi service corps (which the agricultural corps was part of). There were other positions given to them as well, though some of them went rogue or turned to the dark side.